# How to think about following statement in functional analysis?

Tags: functional-analysis

If i am given with a closed densely defined operator $L$ between Hilbert spaces  and is also onto, i.e. $L: D(L) \subset X \to Y$, $X, Y$ are Hilbert spaces and $D(L)$ is dense in $X$.  Can i say that $L$ has a closed range?

I have started with a $y \in \overline{R(L)}$ then there exist a sequence $\{y_n\}$, in $R(L)$ such that $y_n \to y$. Then as $L$ is onto for each $y_n$ there exist a $x_n \in D(L)$, such that $L(x_n) = y_n$. i am not using denseness still. How to go futher?

Comment: If $L$ is onto then certainly $L(D(L)) = Y$ and $Y$ is closed so $L$ has a closed range....

Comment: ok , this is the meaning of onto here.